Reality Check: Would night-vision be necessary for Paleolithic groups to survive extra long, moonless nights?
Assuming they are equivalent to Middle Paleolithic mankind (around ~60,000 BCE), meaning they have access to trade, clothing, (possibly) projectile weapons and the like. The world in question in tidally locked to a binary planet partner, meaning half the world is perpetually facing the "moon" but the other half is perpetually facing away, making night time on this side very dark. This moonless side is what the question is asking about.
The days are around 60 hours long, and depending on the time of year, anywhere from 22.5 to 37.5 hours of the day would be almost completely pitch black with only the stars to illuminate the environment. I looked into real life evidence of pre-historic human behavior and from what I found, people mostly didn't hunt at night and spent that time doing other activities, but with such a long night time I'm not sure that's an option.
As it currently stands, my explanation is that groups of humans simply didn't migrate to this side of the planet, and just stuck to the section where the moon is visible. Only until these groups evolved better night vision over thousands of years did they venture to the far side. The reason is because I believe that EITHER:

Hunting at night is too difficult due to lack of visibility and competition with better noctural predators
Groups can not prepare/ preserve enough food during daytime hours to last them all night. Whether due to lack of knowledge/ tech, or simply because they're too busy.

or both.
The "night vision" in question wouldn't be nearly as good as a cat or owl, only the bare minimum needed to see better than they currently can. So the question is basically: How reasonable are these assumptions? Would night vision be a requirement to hunt at night, or could they somehow find ways to make it work? I would consider "survive" to mean: keeping a decently sized group (~25 - 100+ people) fed, and able to last for multiple generations while being entirely within the far side of the planet.

Another general assumption I made was that fire can't be used to assist in seeing while hunting because the fire would alert any prey of their location.  If there's more info needed to give an answer please ask.
Also I had a couple questions recently that were marked as too broad/ story-based, so I'm not sure if this question is written properly enough to be answered, I'm pretty sure this is more factual than opinion based though.

On clear nights, ordinary unenhanced humans can see well enough with just starlight to walk around without bumping into things. For it to be truely dark you need cloud cover (or be in a forest etc.) in addition to the lack of a moon.

The inability to hunt/gather enough food in a long day to last them through a long night is not plausible.

I've deleted the [tag:internal-consistency] tag because it has one, specific purpose including rules and you're not addressing the purpose or meeting the rules. We don't have a policy regarding review-my-idea questions because they fall so far outside Stack Exchange's rules that they remain off-topic. VTC:Not About Worldbuilding per the [help]. You've already built your world. Our job's already been done. (Per the [tour], we're not a discussion forum and inviting comment about a completed worldbuilding idea is exactly that.) And per the [help/dont-ask], inviting opinions is prohibited.

We have a strict one question per post policy here. The reasonableness of assumptions is entirely subjective and often depends on context as mentioned above asking for oppions is not suitable here. As for your other questions: Whether a species that primarily uses sight to hunt need a way of seeing in the dark to hunt in the dark answers itself you don't need us. Asking could they find some other way is much more of a brainstorming than is suitable for here. You get to decide if and how they manage to do so in your world.

The mutations that would improve the night vision would happen at random. Before those happen, your people need to be able to survive. After those happen, the first person with it needs to have a some advantage over the rest, increasing odds of survival and reproduction, or it should be seen as a desired trait. Low light vision is mostly because of rods in your eyes not the cones for colour. I expect a diminished ability to see colours, or even partial colour blindness to happen more often in your people. Which will potentially hinder them during the short day.

@JBH You're VTC'ing because the question violates a policy that you already stated does not exist? I've been trying to work on asking questions that follow correct format, but I really thought this was the same as other RC questions. As this and other RC questions for example, the general format is something like "Here's my already-built idea + some info; does it make sense?"... Is there an important detail I'm missing in my own Q that makes it different?

(*continued)  the only thing I could notice being possibly wrong is that I worded the question in a way that makes it sound opinionated "How reasonable is this?"  rather than "How possible/ plausible/ realistic is this?" but that's essentially just wording

Starlight and auroras can actually be bright enough to navigate by. Perhaps not bright enough to do precise placement of a spear or to track blood spots, but enough to use other hunting techniques.

@Foosic17 I'm voting to close because you're depending on a behavior that is at this time specifically excluded by Stack Exchange. Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum and avoids questions that are intrinsically opinion-based (on WB: no ability to objectively choose a best answer). How you ask questions on WB is insanely important.  And for the record, both "how reasonable is this?" and "how possible/plausible/realistic is this?" are closable questions. We're here to help you  build your world, not judge how well you've done it. Questions must lead to an objective best answer.

Stone age people used fire to hunt. It wasn't so they could see the prey. It was to hem the prey in.
Many island people use fire to fish, and you catch a LOT of flying fish this way (which are delicious), they jump at the light and you have a net.
With hunter gathers in particular, they don't tend to spend the night sleeping as we do, they do various things, they chase the wife around, sleep a few hours, make something, sleep a few more, chat etc,. And it's not a difficult life for most. Just a few hours a day takes care of their needs, a few more prepping tools and food. They have a lot of leisure time. Only the ones in extreme environments have issues.
So I don't think they'd have to evolve night vision for hunting purposes. But they might develop it just because they live in a dark environment. Having said that we have communities that have nights that last over 2 months and they haven't evolved night vision.

marking as accepted, pointed out how hunter gatherers have lots of freetime they could use to prepare for night.  I agree after people pointed it out, I don't think night vision is absolutely necessary for hunting but like you said they'll probably develop it slowly anyways.

Blue eyes (and green to a lesser degree), it's not full on night vision but those with lighter coloured eyes do have have noticeably better night sight, that has not been merely the subject of comment but also study, which confirms it, there are papers on it to be found somewhere.. less of the light received by the eye is absorbed by the eyes own pigment etc. or some such .. and ethnically those with lighter coloured eyes do tend to be those towards areas where nights are longer, so perhaps it can be said that some of us have evolved for night vision, a little bit, after a fashion? ;)

The natural mechanisms that allow mammals to have night vision are incompatible with decent color vision, and far-sight. The poor level of night vision chimps have is the best humans could get without diminishing their chances at hunting and gathering during the day.
I would rather leave their vision alone, and focus on giving them enhanced hearing, smell and touch, or just make them culturally more skilled at functioning in the dark. Human-being equivalents are smart and powerful enough that they should be able to survive, function, gather and even hunt in absolute darkness.
Also note: Paleolithic humans were usually leisure cultures. They spent most of their time resting, playing, mating, crafting tools and conserving energy. Hunting and gathering only took a fraction of their time, and could be all done in the morning of their short day. The extra hours of night simply mean they would spend more time by the fire, boinking, singing, spinning stories and scrawling cave-art.
